# getShell.pack() not working for custom Canvas extension

Tags: java, button, layout, canvas, eclipse-rcp

I'm using a customized "button" implementation for Eclipse RCP, however, the problem with this implementation is, that the `getShell.pack()` call does not correctly take into account this "button" instances, that is, it does the same as if these "button" instances weren't present in the dialog. Here's the image to illustrate:

[image]

Also, here is the implementation of the "button": http://pastebin.com/gWufPpb5

As you can see, its an extension of a Canvas, but if I tried putting a Canvas instance into my dialog and it was taken into account correctly, so this "button" implementation maybe ruined some Canvas method/variable, which helps `getShell.pack()` to compute the right size of the dialog, but can't seem to figure out which.

**So, what I need to know is which property/method of each of the widgets (the same one for all, I suppose) inside the dialog the `getShell().pack()` is calling when computing, so I can figure out where the this custom "button" is ruining the computation of the dialog layout.**

EDIT:

The code for the layout:

```
    GridData gridData;
    Composite newContainer;

    mainLayout = new GridLayout(2, true);
    mainLayout.marginHeight = 5;
    mainLayout.marginWidth = 5;
    mainLayout.marginLeft = 5;
    mainLayout.marginRight = 5;
    mainLayout.horizontalSpacing = 15;
    mainLayout.verticalSpacing = 10;

    newContainer = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    newContainer.setLayout(mainLayout);
```

Answer (score 0):

The method

```
public Point computeSize(int wHint, int hHint, boolean changed)
```

on each control is called during `pack` processing. Exactly how the size is used depends on the Layout you are using.

Comment: Yeah I thought so. See my edit, I've added layout code.